# JSoup returning symbols in place of hiphens and apostrophe

Tags: java, jsoup

I use JSoup to extract the contents of a URL as HTML. But in place of characters like '-' (Hiphen), and ' (Apostrophe), I get weird symbols. I dont see these symbols through view page source.

Below is the code I use:

```
String url = "http://www.novotreeminds.com/job-details.html#chief";

org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(url).get();
document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(20000)
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .ignoreContentType(true).execute().parse();

document.outputSettings(new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
    System.out.println(document);
```

In the extracted contents, instead of

> Experience: 6 – 10 Years

I see:

> Experience: 6 � 10 Years

This happens in the case of apsotrophe as well. I also see another square-like-symbol instead of the above weird symbol.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5vHH.png)

Thanks,
Akhila

Hi @AHungerArtist,

i have tried the code below (specified the character encoding used in the URL)

```
File input = new File("/home/Documents/NovoTree Minds.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "iso-8859-1", "");
```

But i see the same result

Thanks,
Akhila

Comment: I don't really have an answer for you but I'm sure it's something to do with a difference in character encoding used for the source and your parser. You might see what the default character encoding is in JSoup and then try to set a different one when parsing the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make eclipse print out weird characters in unicode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233775/how-do-i-make-eclipse-print-out-weird-characters-in-unicode)

Comment: This solution seems to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714879/strange-encoding-behaviour-with-jsoup